# How should I go about parsing a JSON response from an API with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, get, alamofire

I am trying to parse a JSON from an API using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON, but am having trouble trying to access the information in the JSON. I need to simply parse the JSON for an item called "ask_price": and also "time_coinapi" but I am not sure how I manage the response, or if I have to use a different method. here is what I have at the moment:

```
class CoinAPIManager {

var prices: [String] = []
var times: [String] = []


static let shared = CoinAPIManager()

func getReq() {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "X-CoinAPI-Key": "Key"
    ]


    Alamofire.request("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/quotes/BITSTAMP_SPOT_BTC_USD/history?time_start=2018-08-21T00:00:00&time_end=2018-08-22T00:00:00&limit=100", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        if let data = try? String(contentsOf: response) {
            let json = JSON(parseJSON: data)


            parse(json: json)


        }



}



    func parse(json: JSON) {
        for result in json[].arrayValue {
            let price = result["ask_price"].stringValue


        }

    }

}
}
```

and I have also tried this:

```
func getReq() {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "X-CoinAPI-Key": "Key"
    ]


    Alamofire.request("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/quotes/BITSTAMP_SPOT_BTC_USD/history?time_start=2018-08-21T00:00:00&time_end=2018-08-22T00:00:00&limit=100", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            // Do whatever here
            return

        case .success(let data):
            // First make sure you got back a dictionary if that's what you expect
            guard let json = data as? [String : AnyObject] else {
                print("Failed to get expected response from webserver.")
                return
            }

            // Then make sure you get the actual key/value types you expect
            guard var price = json["ask_price"] as? Double else {
                    print("Failed to get data from webserver")
                    return
            }



}
```

What am I doing wrong? this is how the JSON looks:

```
[
  {
"symbol_id": "BITSTAMP_SPOT_BTC_USD",
"time_exchange": "2013-09-28T22:40:50.0000000Z",
"time_coinapi": "2017-03-18T22:42:21.3763342Z",
"ask_price": 770.000000000,
"ask_size": 3252,
"bid_price": 760,
"bid_size": 124
  },
  {
"symbol_id": "BITSTAMP_SPOT_BTC_USD",
"time_exchange": "2013-09-28T22:40:50.0000000",
"time_coinapi": "2017-03-18T22:42:21.3763342",
"ask_price": 770.000000000,
"ask_size": 3252,
"bid_price": 760,
"bid_size": 124
  }
]
```

previous question deleted and reposted due to large mistake

Comment: FYI - instead of using multiple third party libraries, use the provided tools - URLSession and JSONDecoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your response to SwiftyJSON object like this

```
Alamofire.request("https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/quotes/BITSTAMP_SPOT_BTC_USD/history?time_start=2018-08-21T00:00:00&time_end=2018-08-22T00:00:00&limit=100", headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)

        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            // Do whatever here
            return

        case .success:
            // First make sure you got back a dictionary if that's what you expect
                let responseJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if responseJSON.count != 0 {
                    print(responseJSON)
                    //do whatever you want with your object json
                }
        }
}
```

i suggest in your ApiManager you can use completion blocks to manage asyncronous request, check the next code.

```
  class func getRequestWithoutParams(didSuccess:@escaping (_ message: JSON) -> Void, didFail: @escaping (_ alert:UIAlertController)->Void){



    Alamofire.request("http://foo.bar"),method: .post,parameters: parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default,headers:nil).responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result{
                case .success:
                    let res = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    didSuccess(res)
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let done = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(done)
                    didFail(alert)
                }
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Swift 4, you should be able to use `codable` to solve it:

```
struct YourStructure: Codable {

   let symbol_id: String?
   let time_exchange: String?
   let ask_price: String?

   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     case symbol_id = "symbol_id"
     case time_exchange = "time_exchange"
     case ask_price = "ask_price"
    }
}
```

And then parse it with `JSONDecoder`

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let parsedData = decoder.decode(YourStructure.self, from: "YourJsonData")
```